# phpmailer noname attachment

Tags: email, attachment, phpmailer

I'm using phpmailer to send email. But all of my emails are send with noname attachement. I already checked if variables are set before I use addAttachemnt function and they are. It looks like this:

```
$fname = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$fTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

            $mail = new PHPMailer();
            $mail->From = "mymail@mymail.com";  
            $mail->FromName = "mymail.com"; //moje meno 
            $mail->IsHTML(true);
            $mail->IsSMTP();
            $mail->Host = "smtp.mymail.com";
            $mail->Subject = "Subject";
            $mail->AddAddress($email);
            echo $fnameZivotopis;
            $mail->AddAttachment($fTmpName,$fname);
            $mail->Body = $msg;
            $mail->Send(); // send message
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use AddStringAttachment(string $att_file_data, string $att_file_name, ...).