# PHPMailer giving me "noname" attachments

Tags: php, phpmailer, email-attachments

My problem is exactly like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062939/phpmailer-noname-attachment) one, I am getting the attachments without the extension, if I put the extension to the file manually, the file is still not recognized. What could cause this?

This is the attachment-adding part, rest is standard:

```
  foreach($_FILES['uploads']['name'] as $key => $file){
    $mail->attachment[] = array($_FILES['uploads']['tmp_name'][$key], $_FILES['uploads']['name'][$key]);
    $mail->boundary = "_b" . md5(uniqid(time()));
  }
```

EDIT:

In the beginning of every attachment I get this:

```
name="phpmailer.inc.php"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="phpmailer.inc.php"
```

is this normal?

EDIT:
Also, I copied the files to the server and I am adding them to the attachment from there, still, all the files are "noname" and with the correct size.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not use `$_FILES['uploads']['tmp_name'][$key]` file as an attachment as `$_FILES['uploads']['tmp_name']` are temperory files.

First you need to upload that document/file to the server and than attached it to the mail. Than only it will work.

Comment: But that would mean I have to empty the folder manually... And the files in temp should be the same files, or what exactly happens there then?

Comment: @SEROK just upload file with "move_uploaded_file()" and than attached from uploaded folder and not from temperory location.